# How to override new password on old password in SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, overriding

I am making online mcq project.

We have provided 'Forgot Password' option. After the student clicks on it and the OTP is sent, the student is then supposed to add his new password. The new password is then stored in the database but I am Not getting code of how to Override the new password with old password in SQL database.

I don't want to make too many Columns, so I want to override and bring a new password in the place of old one in the database to be read.

Comment: it isn't obvious what you're asking... but it sounds like you just want to `UPDATE` a row in a database, and `SET` a specific column to a new value - is that right? and... you meant "salted password hash", not "password", right?

Comment: `UPDATE Table SET HashedPassword = @NewValue WHERE UserID = @UserID`

Answer (score -1):

```
Declare @UserName NVarChar(30)    
Declare @Password NVarChar(30)    
Declare @Application NVarChar(255)    
Declare @PasswordSalt NVarChar(128)    

set @UserName = 'UserName'    
set @Password = 'Pass'    
set @Application = '/Application'    
Set @PasswordSalt = (SELECT 1 PasswordSalt FROM aspnet_Membership WHERE UserID IN    (SELECT UserID FROM aspnet_Users u, aspnet_Applications a WHERE u.UserName=@UserName and a.ApplicationName = @Application AND u.ApplicationId = a.ApplicationId))    

Exec dbo.aspnet_Membership_ResetPassword @Application, @UserName, @Password, 10, 10, @PasswordSalt, -5
```